# What part of speech is the that clause after 'I'm sure'?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

fellow grammarians.

When it comes to a clause, we'd naturally understand that each of them has a lexical class to it, and, the part of speech they serve as in a sentence.

Adjective + that clause has never been a rare usage. It's rather easy to get right the that clause in sentence 'It's important that this will be done' for example. The 'it' here is a formal subject, hence the that clause being the true subject. And the lexical class of this that clause is noun. Therefore, it is both a subject clause, and a noun clause.

But in the case of 'I'm sure + that clause', this gets me confused. 'I am sure' being a complete sentence which ends with a predicative, I don't know what the that clause after the predicative 'sure' serves to be in terms of part of speech. Sure, it should be a noun clause as always, but, what part of speech is it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not identifying noun clauses correctly yet; the that-clause after "sure" is not at all a noun clause. Here is a link giving explanations:https://www.wikihow.com/Identify-a-Noun-Clause . The gist of it is this: "Simply put, a noun clause is a **dependent clause** that **takes the place of a noun** in the sentence. […] If a dependent clause can stand in for a person, place, or thing, then it’s a noun clause." If you replace it by a noun and the resulting sentence makes sense, then you have a noun clause. For instance "I'm sure people." makes no sense at all.

Comment: @LPH. Traditional grammar does classify the _that_ clauses in the OP's examples as noun clauses. But the term 'noun clause' is a misnomer, particularly as many of the so-called 'noun clauses' cannot be replaced by nouns, as the OP's examples demonstrate. The OP's examples are best classified as declarative content clauses (the default kind of finite subordinate clause) functioning as complement of the adjectives "important" / "sure". There is nothing at all to be gained by calling them 'noun clauses'

Comment: @BillJ "That" clauses, when adjectival complements are, as you say, classified as nominal clauses, but in this case a noun phrase does not fit in; what is needed is a prepositional phrase. The question is not one of "gaining" something but of describing truly what is the nature of  the grammatical element considered. Does it fulfill the functions of a noun or not? It seems  that it does: subject, object; only nouns (NP) can have those functions. So, I believe that grammar does classify judiciously this element as being of the nature of the noun (there might be difficulties as here, though).

Comment: @LPH Why? It doesn't matter whether or not the clause can be replaced by a noun --  trad grammar still calls it a 'noun clause'. But modern grammar does not use the term 'noun clause' -- it's meaningless. Finite subordinate clauses are **not** noun clauses under any circumstances. They have their own classifications, i.e. content, comparative and relative. The first two almost always function as complements, while the relatives are modifiers. There is nothing to be gained by calling content clauses 'noun clauses'. Why would anyone want to?

Comment: @BillJ It is a useful nomenclature because it describes a category of clauses that definitely have in common a precise syntactical characteristic that sets them apart from other clauses, no more than that, except for the fact that it is simply true.

Comment: @LPH It's not true and it's not useful. There is no category of finite subordinate clause called 'noun clause'. I've already explained that to you. You're quoting schoolbook / ESL grammar, not scholarly technical grammar.

Comment: @TimmyHam:  As you can see, there are several conflicting and confusing terminology sets, and constant argument about which is more appropriate. To answer your question, the _that_ that introduces the clause is usually called a Complementizer, because its function is to introduce (and mark) complement clauses like _that this will be done_. I would call that a Noun clause, the extraposed subject of _be important_. But that's not part of either of the two variant terminologies discussed here.

Comment: @JohnLawler Reassuring help here! It was needed!

Comment: Thanks for all the input here; I very much appreciate it. I do agree with @LPH on the fact that grammatically, what is needed after 'be sure' is a prepositional phrase, not a noun, because only an adverbial element can serve as the complement to an adjective, which is universally true across all languages as far as I know. At least many grammarians do always regard that-clauses as noun clauses, which, however, doesn't make sense when it comes to expressions like 'be sure/be certain that'. Maybe the usage hasn't been strictly grammatical in the first place but has been accepted as valid anyway.

Comment: @TimmyHan Nevertheless, trad grammar calls declarative content clauses 'noun clauses', which simply makes no sense, particularly because they can't always be replaced by a noun. Further, there can be no justification for saying that the bracketed clauses in "She told me [that he fainted]" and "He was so exhausted [that he fainted]" belong to a different categories. They are both declarative content clauses functioning respectively as complement of "told", and as a complement in clause structure (licensed by "so").

Comment: @BillJ The preferable phrase is _makes no sense **to me**_; otherwise it sounds like The Voice Of God, which I doubt is your intention. And that's before I even finished reading the first sentence. tl;dr

Comment: @BillJ The that clause in a [so adj that clause] construction is by no means a noun clause. It's very obvious that a noun clause functions as a noun; we call them clauses because they appear in the form of a clause. So the parts of speech they may serve as are exactly those which a noun serves as. All of this is clear to me. I'd say the that clause in [so... that...] is an adverbial element which denotes the consequence to the event described in the main clause. That being said, it does seem the that clause in [be sure that] may function as an adverbial one imo.

Comment: @TimmyHan The first part of your comment is wrong: _that_ clauses don’t function as nouns. Noun is not a function but a word category (POS) that includes such items as "house", "tree", "hatred", "London", etc. Clauses are never nouns; they belong to certain categories where they typically function as subject, complement or modifier. In your examples, the that clauses belong to the category **declarative content clause**. They are functioning as **extraposed subject** in the first, and **complement** of "sure" in the second. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *It's important* [*that this is done*].
>
> [2] *I'm sure* [*that this will be done*].

The lexical class of the bracketed elements is 'declarative content clause'.

In [2] The subordinate clauses combines with the adjective it complements to form a larger adjective phrases functioning as predicative complement of "be". By contrast, in [1] (an extraposed construction) the predicative complement is just "important", just as it is in the basic, non-extraposed, version (see below).

I would strongly recommend dropping the term 'noun clause'. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Note that in the extrapostion constuction in [1], the subject is the dummy pronoun "it". The *that* clause is an extraposed subject, but that doesn't mean it's a kind of subject -- it's an element in extraposed position, outside the verb phrase corresponding to the subject of the basic version:

[*That this is done*] *is important*.

Comment: "That this is done" does not have the function of adjective complement; its function  is called "real subject", whereas you call the subject "it" an artificial subject or dummy subject (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects). Same thing in "It's important to do this.".

Comment: This analysis makes of "that this is done"  the complement of its own predicative complement; that is not possible.

Comment: The Cambridge reference I provide uses the term "real subject"; that is not ESL. //If you have a subject it is the subject of some verb and you **can't** have "That this is done is."; this again is nonsense.

Comment: @LPH "That this is done" in [1] is not called a 'real subject' but an extraposed subject, as I said in my answer. It's only the subject in the non-extraposed version, as shown in my answer.. The grammatical subject of [1] is the dummy pronoun "it". In [2] "that this will be done" is complement of "sure", with which it combines to form the larger PC "sure that this will be done"

Comment: This is merely piled on descriptive terminology; that is true, it is placed in a particular way; nevertheless, it remains a subject and has to be the subject of a verb, which can't be but "is"; so, there has to be a PC.

Comment: @LPH What remains a subject? No grammarian would say that "that this is done" is the grammatical subject of [1]. That would be a ridiculous mistake. We know that "it" is the subject because it inverts with the verb to form an interrogative: "Is it important that this is done?" The PC in [1] is just "important", just as it is in the non-extraposed version.

Comment: Interesting, but now if "it" is still a dummy subject, and it has to be, "that this is done" has to be the extraposed subject; it seems that this adds no new information.